# AWS Route 53 DNS setup

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I bought a domain via Amazon Route 53.

Everything worked fine (couple of months) until I deleted the Hosted Zone from Route 53 and tried to recreate it.

Now I'm not able to get my website back online. It looks like it's sticking to old DNS which point to a no more existing load balancer and when I create a new Hosted Zone I'm not able to really change NS records.

The website is actually reachable because if I put the load balancer DNS or address in the browser it works.

Looks like Amazon used a service called www.gandi.net to actually purchase the domain and I suspect the problem could be registrar DNS delegation doesn't work properly.

I'm very new to the whole DNS thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Doing a `dig +trace` my domain i get NS records back which are different from the ones I put in Route 53. If I put one of those NS ips as my laptop DNS in network configuration I am able to reach my website via domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to solve it. I needed to go to Route 53 domain's section and update NS servers there, inputing to those used in the Hosted Zone.

Comment: The take-away, here, is "don't delete a live hosted zone in Route 53" because when you put it back, the authoritative name servers always change.  This is the expected behavior.  If for any reason you ever feel like this is the right thing to do, create the new hosted zone *first*.  You can create more than one with the same domain at the same time, then change your name servers (with the registrar) to the new hosted zone, and test, before deleting the old one.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You're correct. I was missing the registrar part, whose name servers are managed via Route 53 itself, so I was kinda expecting creating a hosted zone with the same name as my domain name was enough to change the name servers. I lost a whole lot of time before understanding I was badly wrong.